# csv uploader throwing nil or empty error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a site that has an a table called `orders`, the order model, and a `csv_files_controller` (separate from the orders controller).

in the model I have the following:

```
  def self.import(csv_file)
    CSV.foreach(csv_file.path, headers: true) do |row|
      Order.create! row.to_hash
    end
  end
```

in the `csv_files_controller` I have the following:

```
class CsvFilesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @csv_file = CsvFile.new
  end

  def create
    @csv_file = CsvFile.new(params[:csv_file])
    if @csv_file.save
      Order.import
      redirect_to csv_file, notice: "Orders uploaded successfully"
    end
  end

  def show
    @csv_file = CsvFile.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @csv_file }
    end
  end
end
```

my `upload_form` partial being rendered by a page in the orders views from `csv_files` views:

```
<%= form_for @csv_file do |f| %>
  <div class="controls">
  <%= f.file_field :csv_file, accept: 'csv', :class => 'btn btn-xs btn-info' %>    
  <%= f.submit "Upload Orders", :class => 'btn btn-xs btn-success' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

my `routes.rb` also has

```
resources :csv_files
```

when I try to load the page for the uploading I am getting a `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty error`.  I am not sure what I have done wrong for it to say that.

Now if I change the `form_for` to :`csv_files` the page will load, but it is blank; no browse for file or submit button appear, but the error goes away. Doesn't matter though if the form isn't working.  I am using `rails 4` so I shouldn't need he `:html => {multipart: true}` and even when it was there it didn't change anything.

I can't figure out why it is throwing the error.

Update 9-1-15:

I have made a ton of changes, but now I get 
No route matches [POST] "/orders/upload_page"

but my rake routes shows I have set my post route to :import.

```
resources :orders do   
    collection do
      post :import
      get  :upload_page, as: 'upload_page'
      get  :search, as: 'search'
      get  :csv_report, as: 'csv_report'
      get  :overdue_csv_report, as: 'overdue_csv_report'
    end
  end
```

I don't understand why it is routing post to the upload_page.

Comment: I think you have missed argument  `@csv_file` for `Order.import` method in the controller.

Comment: I tried adding something there, but it made no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was threfold:

1. I got rid of the csv_files controller, etc. and moved all the code to the original orders controller.
2. I was trying to use a form_for .... do |f| and I had to revert to form_tag .... do for the form and spell everything out to get the post to work.
3. code snips:

Model:

```
  def self.import(csv_file)
    CSV.foreach(csv_file, headers: true) do |row|
      Order.create! row.to_hash
    end
  end
```

Controller:

```
  def import
    Order.import(params[:csv_file].tempfile)
    redirect_to orders_path, notice: "Orders imported"
  end
```

form partial:

```
<%= form_tag import_orders_path, multipart: true do %>
  <div class="controls">
  <%= file_field_tag :csv_file, accept: 'csv', :class => 'btn btn-xs btn-info' %>    
  <%= submit_tag "Upload Orders", :class => 'btn btn-xs btn-success' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Routes:

```
  resources :orders do   
    collection do
      post :import
```

I am now working on ensuring that the uploads are using the validations in the model as it seems to be skipping it.